# Where can I buy inexpensive seforim online?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, internet, books-generally

Where can I buy seforim online for inexpensive prices?  I mean real seforim.....not digital ones.

I'm willing to buy seforim either new or second-hand.

Comment: More specific: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14870

Comment: Why not a local brick-and-mortar store? there are usually in every major neighborhood.

Comment: Not an answer, but has anyone experience with Greenfield Judaica? Any recommendations?

Answer (score 10):

If you want used, also try ebay. There are a few Judaica sellers on there and you can get stuff relative inexpensively.  [This seller](http://www.ebay.com/usr/bluebirds15) is the biggest.

Answer (score 7):

- http://www.seforimsets.com/
- http://www.hebrewbooks.org/ to read online (you can also order a print from lulu, or print from your printer)

Answer (score 7):

Try [CheapJewishBooks.com](http://www.amazon.com/gp/aag/main/ref=olp_merch_name_1?ie=UTF8&asin=B0012XTC2Q&isAmazonFulfilled=0&seller=A2HHSEWOB9NKB8). All the profits go to buying Sefarim for people who cannot afford them.

Answer (score 5):

If it is a mainstream book (i.e. sold on amazon) You can normally find a used copy on Amazon. You can usually get a pretty good price if you're willing to buy used books that aren't in perfect condition. For example, [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0910818177) is $20.95 new and only $8.84 used.

Answer (score 5):

http://www.kodeshbook.co.il has very large variety of seforim, only new, for great price. What I like is that they can get you all Artscroll books in Israel for the Artscroll site prices but without the extra sales tax that is added on for purchases in Israel. Service is great considering that it is an Israeli based company, and they really do try to make you happy.

Answer (score 4):

Personally I highly recommend this:
http://www.virtualgeula.com/index.htm
I used it all the time when I lived in the US, because it was often cheaper to have them shipped sea-mail to me, then to buy them from anywhere(including online stores) in the US.  That and he has a knack for finding rare Kabbalah Seforim.

Answer (score 4):

[zolsefer.co.il](http://www.zolsefer.co.il/) usually has the cheapest prices for a very wide range of seforim, plus they have nearly all of them in stock so that your order can be shipped very quickly.

Answer (score 4):

I can definitely recommend our site: [ספרי קודש המדף היהודי](http://www.hamadaf-y.co.il/) as we try to keep on the lowest price online...

Its in 3 languages: Hebrew, English, and French. (the hebrew version is the most developed one) and we working on it all the time- adding new books, developing new functions, sending Jewish books worldwide to every Tzadik who want to learn torah...

Hope you all will enjoy visiting us :)

Answer (score 3):

Try bookfinder.com
I've used them for years (mostly for English titles, but some Hebrew seforim). Got vol 2 of Alei Shur for 15 bucks with free shipping from England to Chicago.

Answer (score 1):

Try [seforimdeals.com](https://seforimdeals.com/store/) they have all new Seforim and very good prices and service

Answer (score 1):

[Nehora.com](http://www.nehora.com/) has a large selection of s'farim, at great prices. For the most part they sell books in Hebrew, but there is section for English and Hebrew/English.

You could also try purchasing books off [eBay](http://www.ebay.com/); there are usually some ridiculous deals on there. One time I got a six-volume Mishnah Berurah set for $20.00!

Answer (score 1):

JewishusedBooks.com definitely, cheapest prices and hard to find Seforim and books

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first answer. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 0):

This site has several comprehensive lists of Mussar books including many little-known, rare, and hard-to-find works: https://www.mussar.center/ Most of the links go to Amazon but the listings there include some of the best details on second-hand books you'll be able to find, especially older editions of the more popular Musar books that often get overlooked because everybody's buying new copies of the more recent editions. I hope this helps!