# What is a good place to buy kabbalah seforim online?

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, mysticism-kabbalah, jewish-books, transactions

I am aware of Nehora and the other sites I could find googling this same inquiry, I'm looking for other recommendations of sites that have a good selection. Specifically I'm looking for Kanfei Yona (Rama mi'Fano) and Sefer Gilgulim (not to be confused with Sha'ar Gilgulim). But a general source for kabbalah seforim would be very helpful.

Comment: Why close?......

Comment: was wondering the same thing, I actually based this on a similar question I saw here http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3960/good-place-online-for-cheap-seforim

Comment: http://seforimbzul.com is a great and inexpensive resource for all kinds of seforim - unfortunately, the more popular items are often sold out, but they are restocked regularly.

Comment: HaRav Ariel Bar Tzadok (www.koshertorah.com) says that everyone is chayav to learn Kabbalah nowadays, and that it is a sin to abstain from doing so.

Comment: @yoel they seemed to have shut down :(

Answer (score 1):

Here is another place to purchase kabbalah seforim online http://www.kabbalah-source.com

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 1):

[Seforim Center](https://seforimcenter.com/) has an excellent selection.

They have both the seforim you mentioned.

**Kanfei Yonah - Rabbi Menachem Azarya of Fano**
https://seforimcenter.com/Product.aspx?ProductID=14339&strReferer=search&PPGR=0

Sefer HaGilgulim - Rabbi Yitzchak Luria
https://seforimcenter.com/Product.aspx?ProductID=12610&strReferer=search&PPGR=0

Answer (score 0):

[Many Sifre Kabala](http://www.zbermanbooks.com/Page.asp?ID=913b66bcca735b3f5c59329b6c3574d7d14ad2a8858e1e4dc7fe&CategoryID=8554)

[Great Selection for Sefaradi Mekubalim](http://www.wslibrary.net/catalog/index.php?cPath=1&osCsid=fa90ef4fc244aed2b79dc26ab39b3028)

For the two specified here:

[Kanfe Yona 24.95$](http://www.seforimcenter.com/product.asp?P_ID=1394&strPageHistory=search&strKeywords=kanfei,yona&numPageStartPosition=1&strSearchCriteria=all&PT_ID=all)

I'm still searching Sefer Hagilulim, and BN BH I'll get back to you.

Comment: Since Sefer Hagilgulim is [on hebrewbooks.org](http://hebrewbooks.org/45024), you could always [order a print copy](http://www.publishyoursefer.com/reprints/id/HB-45024).