# Rov Menashe Klein's Mishnah Halachos 18 vol responsa

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, responsa

I have been searching online as well as in seforim stores and can't seem to find a set of Rov Menashe Klein's Mishnah Halachos Shut set?  Does anyone have any ideas where I could find a set.  Thanks!

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3960/8775.

Comment: Perhaps try to ask in the Shul or call them. Cong Bais Shearim Ungvar
5306 16th Ave Brooklyn, NY 11204
(718) 436-2307 Khal Ungvar
1578 53rd St Brooklyn, NY 11219
(718) 851-0806

Answer (score 3):

It is available [here](http://www.virtualgeula.com/Stock/Books/Show/10439). It is identified as 18 volumes which I assume is the 16 plus novellae on massekhtot.

It is available [here](http://seforimsets.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=567) at SeforimSets.com. [OUT OF STOCK].

Note that pdfs of the entire series are available for free on [Tshuvos.com](http://www.tshuvos.com/tshuvos.asp), [this is the first volume](http://www.tshuvos.com/pdf/mishnehalochos1.pdf).

Comment: I assume that Tshuvos.com was given the rights to post these pdfs, but I haven't confirmed that.

Comment: Thanks for the link really appreciate it!  Unfortunately seforimsets.com says that it is currently out of stock.  I will call them to check when it will be back in print.

Comment: You are very welcome.  Let's see what we can do...

Answer (score 3):

There is almost a complete set of Mishnah Halachos by Rabbi Menashe Klein over here:
[Philadelphiafay Vintage Jewish Book Store](https://www.ebay.com/itm/14-Volum-15-Mishnah-Halachos-Mishneh-Halachot-Ungvar-R-Menashe-Klein-Teshuvos/264169550863?hash=item3d81bb740f:g:6XMAAOSwqoxcUHU1:rk:1:pf:1)

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) 
Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Not available anymore